# TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type PhoneNumber)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using [PhoneNumberField](https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-phonenumber-field) in my django-rest-api application

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(_('phone number'), unique=True)
```

i was successful creating superuser with phonenumber and password.But each time  am running the server i get error `TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type PhoneNumber)` Can someone please help me

```
Stacktrace
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type PhoneNumber)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Emmanuel\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Emmanuel\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 136, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Emmanuel\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "C:\Users\Emmanuel\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 86, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Users\Emmanuel\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 128, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\Emmanuel\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 84, in technical_500_response
    html = reporter.get_traceback_html()
  File "C:\Users\Emmanuel\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 317, in get_traceback_html
    return t.render(c)
  File "C:\Users\Emmanuel\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 208, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Emmanuel\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Emmanuel\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 994, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\Emmanuel\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Emmanuel\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 315, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Emmanuel\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 994, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\Emmanuel\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Emmanuel\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 315, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Emmanuel\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 994, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\Emmanuel\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Emmanuel\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1050, in render
    return render_value_in_context(output, context)
  File "C:\Users\Emmanuel\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1028, in render_value_in_context
    value = force_text(value)
  File "C:\Users\Emmanuel\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\utils\encoding.py", line 76, in force_text
    s = six.text_type(s)
```

Comment: Can you provide the traceback? The error message may not even be coming from this part of your code, and it would be helpful to have the traceback and any code it references.

Comment: Sorry, i edited the question with stacktrace@ShadowRanger

Comment: do you have the `__str__` method in your model? If so, could you provide it?

Comment: Your my hero man! I didnt declare it but it was explicit called with `return self.phone_number` which cause my problem. changing it to `return str(self.phone_number) ` works! Thanks @EvansMurithi

Comment: People voting down my question. At least tell me what is wrong with it!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From [django-phonenumber-field](https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-phonenumber-field) it says:

> The object returned is a PhoneNumber instance, not a string.

You should do something like:

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.phone_number)
```

Comment: This should be donde in the Model

Comment: That's true. Kindly look at [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41288844/typeerror-str-returned-non-string-type-phonenumber/41289235?noredirect=1#comment69780370_41288844) I made on the question

Answer (score 0):

A django-phonenumber-field object is an instance of **<class 'phonenumber_field.phonenumber.PhoneNumber'>**, so you need to convert to a type string for django to present it.

There are several ways to do this, here is one of the ways.

*Add the **str** method to your model:*

```py
def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.phone_number}"
```